# Can't see Crash-free statistics in firebase Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I'm using Crashlytics on firebase but I'm getting this strange error

> To see this data, make sure that your app is using the latest version of Crashlytics

[image]

this is despite the fact I'm using

```
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') { transitive = true }


classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
```

which is the latest version of Crashlytics.
this used to work before but suddenly stopped working, I don't know if it's a bug or I have done something wrong.
does anyone else face the same problem?

the relevant parts build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "io.mironov.smuggler"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation("org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version") {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:transition:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v7:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"

    implementation 'com.github.humazed:RoomAsset:v1.0-beta5'
    implementation 'com.github.humazed:KotlinAndroidUtils:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.humazed:NetworkErrorView:1.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.humazed:BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper:77317cf9e2'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'

    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.6@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original@aar'

    implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.yotadevices.widget:rtlviewpager:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:v1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.DanielMartinus:Stepper-Touch:0.6'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.paperonboarding:paper-onboarding:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ome450901:SimpleRatingBar:1.3.6'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0-rc1'

    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    implementation 'com.otaliastudios:nestedscrollcoordinatorlayout:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.0.4'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.kizitonwose.time:time-android:1.0.1'

    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$firebase_version"

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') { transitive = true }

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$gms_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$gms_version"

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.23.0'

    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

    implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:3.0.1'
    kapt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:3.0.1'

    debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

}



  buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
        anko_version = '0.10.2'
        room_version = '1.0.0'
        support_version = '27.0.2'
        firebase_version = '11.8.0'
        gms_version = '11.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.mironov.smuggler:smuggler-plugin:0.12.13"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the firebase core implemented? (`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'`)

Comment: yes, of course, I double checked that I have the latest versions of all firebase libs.

Comment: I upgraded from `crashlytics:2.7.1` to 2.9.0 about a week ago.  I see valid statistics for some filter settings (version and/or date range) but the display you posted for others.  I don't yet see a clear pattern, but I'm starting to suspect this is a bug in 2.9.0

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Could you add your full build.gradle so I could look into more for any folks hitting this?

Comment: Ok, mike I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that all looks good to me so this is even stranger. In this case, can you enable debug mode by adding this line to your AndroidManifest.xml <meta-data android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" /> and then use this init: final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
        .kits(new Crashlytics())
        .debuggable(true)           // Enables Crashlytics debugger
        .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);

Then build and run the app, log some events and share LogCat? Was hoping before that the build.gradle would show the issue.

Comment: Also, what time filter are you looking at?

Comment: @MikeBonnell:  I am seeing the same issue as humazed.  I enabled debug mode per your instructions and captured this log output:  https://gist.github.com/Bob-Snyder/ae4db321a91879a94f1ff0feb84880a8

Comment: @MikeBonnell: Another observation:  When I refresh the Crashlytics page in the Firebase console, I momentarily see what appears to be correct statistics before they are replaced with _To see this data, make sure your app is using the latest version of Crashlytics_

Comment: the same thing happens to me as Bob says it momentarily appear and disappear.

Comment: Thanks both, with your help, we found the bug and are working on the fix. Should be a few days before it goes live.

Comment: Is the bug fixed by firebase? My 'Crash free statistics' stopped showing value all of a sudden. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for not showing Crashlytics in my project is that I also have Fabric implemented in project. Remove all Fabric dependency/code.
Also remove Script that looks like this:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"
```